# i want to use heaters to heat small area

Tags: resistors

Hi I want to heat an area of .5sqare mm to a a temperature of 100°c to 110°c and many such squares will be user in a matrix close to each other, do anyone have idea about any small heater which I can use in my application.. Please help. Thanks...

Comment: Use SMD resistors. Give PWM to adjust temperature.

Comment: Why do you need this? It could be hard to achieve the temperature you specified. What is the ambient temperature?

Comment: Explain further. If you're putting them in a matrix do you want different temperatures at adjacent points? (If not then why such small heaters? If so, how will you insulate?) What is the application? A thermal printhead (fax machine, 'pay-and-display' parking ticket printer, etc.) is a line of tiny heaters on a ceramic substrate.

Comment: Hi thank you for your reoly. The ambient temp. Would be from 30 to matrix The temperature will be the same on each square/heater only particular square will be switched on on the matrix. The application is a matrix printer. So depending on the character i want to print the Respective square will be turned on in a matrix of 5x5 by a microcontroller. I hope I have explained it properly. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a PRT (platinum resistance thermometer) (or RTD) as the heating element. You can drive it with a PWM power signal to heat it up then you can momentarily switch it to a monitor circuit (every once per second or so) and measure the temperature. You can get them as 0603 and 0805 sizes commonly: -

[image]
[image]

[**PRT or RTD link**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistance_thermometer)

Comment: Hi Andy aka thanks for the reply. where will i get these PRT and RTD so that i can practically use these this and see. thanks

Comment: I don't know where you live but the suppliers I use are Farnell, RS, digikey and mouser - they all sell them.

Comment: Hey Andy, Thanks for the reply. Do I use the RTD as heating element and also get a temperature measure from it or else do I have to measure the temperature of the rtd with an external device.

Comment: You develop a circuit that switches between injection power into the RTD then measuring the RTD's resistance. That's what I'd do.

Comment: Hey Andy, Thanks for the reply. can you share any circuit so that i can try it practically with the specification of the RTD. thanks.

Comment: I haven't got a circuit that springs to mind. I know I did this back in the early 80s on one job but I can't remember the details.

Comment: no problem andy... thanks a lot for giving me valuable information.

Answer (score 0):

Heating elements are nothing but a resistor which consume electrical power to give out heat. With the constraints you have given, the best bet seems to be using a 0402 package resistor directly soldered on the PCB. Here is a size chart of common packages:

[image: Package dimensions]

0402 has the area that you need. However it might be difficult to solder manually depending upon your soldering skills. Once you have chose to go down this road, you can start making the matrix using these resistors. You can use PWM to control the temperature of these individual resistors. Exact feedback loop control might be difficult though, given the size of your application. You need to do some trials to figure out what duty cycle gives you what temperature.